# How to divide two aggregates to get a percentage

Tags: sql, count, sum, max, presto

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of volume processed versus the target volume.  I've been able to calculate out the Volume Worked and the Target Volume separately, but when I try to get the percentage my results keep rounding out to the closest integer, I've cast them in decimal as I'm expecting the results to come out as decimal rather than in a percentage.

```
(CAST(COUNT(job_id) AS DECIMAL)/
(CAST(ROUND(SUM(review_time)/1000,2)/MAX(CAST(target_review_time AS DECIMAL)) AS DECIMAL))) AS Percentage
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are facing integer division. All operands to the operation are integers, so the result is given as an integer as well.

You can force a decimal context by turning one of the operands to a decimal:

```
COUNT(job_id) / SUM(review_time) / MAX(target_review_time) / 1000.0  AS Percentage
```

You can then `round()` the result to the precision you want:

```
ROUND(COUNT(job_id) / SUM(review_time) / MAX(target_review_time) / 1000.0, 2)  AS Percentage
```

Note: if `job_id` is not nullable, then `COUNT(job_id)` is more efficiently written `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this basically do what you want?

```
COUNT(*) * 1.0 / ( (SUM(Review_Time) / 1000.0) / MAX(target_review_time) )
```

If so, cast and round on the entire expression.